# Displaying categories once with multiple data in the while loop with html tags

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been trying to solve this problem and have find a lot of solutions but still can't get to work. I am so frustrated with the codes and I think I will just do it step by step then instead of lumping it altogether and get it work at once.

Right now my tables are:

```
categories | name
fashion    | chanel
fashion    | prada
cafes      | starbucks
cafes      | tcc
dining     | kfc
dining     | macdonalds
```

What I want to achieve is

```
1) Echo-ing out the categories <h1>fashion</h1> with once instead of duplicating and <ul> if it is starting on a new category

2) Echo-ing out all the <li>name</li> no matter how many of names are under that fashion

3) Echo-ing out </ul> if it is the last name in that fashion
```

And so on for the rest of the categories. This is currently what my mind is thinking of and I do not know whether is this practical or not.

I have tried using this way:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM floor_directory WHERE level='$level' ORDER BY categories");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                if($previousVal != $row['categories']){
                     $data .= '<h1>'.$row['categories'].'</h1><ul class="shop_listing">';
                     $previousVal = $row['categories'];
                }
                 $data .= '<li>
                           <p class="float_left">'.$row['name'].'</p>
                           </li></ul>';
            }
```

Which I know there is something wrong in the looping of the li with the closing ul. This is where I am stuck for very long time and unable to find any solution anywhere. No matter what I do, foreach for different categories, if else, I still can't get anywhere near.

The result I get is either:

```
<h1>fashion</h1>
<ul class="shop_listing">
<li><p>chanel</p></li>
</ul>
<li><p>prada</p></li>

<h1>dining</h1>
<ul class="shop_listing">
<li><p>kfc</p></li>
</ul>
<li><p>macdonald</p></li>
```

Or:

```
<h1>fashion</h1>
<ul class="shop_listing">
<li><p>chanel</p></li>
<li><p>prada</p></li>

<h1>dining</h1>
<ul class="shop_listing">
<li><p>kfc</p></li>
<li><p>macdonald</p></li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Hope you guys can help me out please. For those who just put links and commented read more on that, don't input your answers here. I don't need that, I am already very confused and I am just a beginner in this. I am glad if someone is willing to guide or even explain to me why my code doesn't work and why the solutions given will work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is create a new array using your `category` as a key and put all names belonging to that category into an array within that. Loop through the new array and create your HTML.

PHP

```
$temp_array=array();//temporary array

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM floor_directory WHERE level='$level' ORDER BY categories");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $temp_array[$row['categories']][]=$row['name'];//put data into temporary array
}

foreach($temp_array AS $category=>$names){
    $data.='<h1>'.$category.'</h1><ul class="shop_listing">';
    foreach($names AS $name){
        $data.='<li>
               <p class="float_left">'.$name.'</p>
               </li>';
    }
    $data.='<ul>';
}
```

Not tested, but it should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks! This works like a finally! Can you explain to me what is the meaning of this $temp_array[$row['categories']][] ? So if let's say I have other field to display besides name, I have to create 1 more line of $temp_array[$row['categories']][] ?

Comment: $temp_array is a place to store and sort your data into a way that's easier for you to use. If you wanted to add more information the changes you would have to make would depend on what you wanted to do with that data. Read up on **Multidimensional Arrays**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM floor_directory WHERE level='$level' ORDER BY 

    categories");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    if($previousVal != $row['categories']){
                         if($data) {
                               $data .= "</ul>";
                         }
                         $data .= '<h1>'.$row['categories'].'</h1><ul class="shop_listing">';
                         $previousVal = $row['categories'];
                    }
                     $data .= '<li>


                     <p class="float_left">'.$row['name'].'</p>
                                   </li>';
                    }
$data .= "</ul>";
```

Comment: Thanks! This works too! Is it possible that you can explain to me the logic? As in why is there an extra if $data?

Comment: Very simple. Basically you want to add </ul> after each time the loop has executed to "end" your unordered list. So you just add into the loop the </ul>. However, it must be at the beginning in order to be able to check if it is the first time the loop has started (as in that case you do not add the </ul> tag.